# Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to save ice candidates to firebase using from this code

```
  const callDoc = firestore.collection('calls').doc();
  const offerCandidates = callDoc.collection('offerCandidates');
  const answerCandidates = callDoc.collection('answerCandidates');

  callInput.value = callDoc.id;
```

and using angular like this

```
this.callDoc = this.firestore.collection('calls').doc();
this.offerCandidates = this.callDoc.collection('offerCandidates');
this.answerCandidates = this.callDoc.collection('answerCandidates');
this.pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
  event.candidate && this.offerCandidates.add(event.candidate.toJSON());
};
this.callDoc.set({ offer });
```

but when i run this, this error appears

[image]

why this is happening?

i have set this on my firebase

[image]

Comment: can you share the share constrcutor method where you have added this angular code

Comment: `constructor(
    private afDb: AngularFireDatabase,
    private router: Router
  ) { }`

Comment: There seems like two problems, first private afDb: AngularFireDatabase should be private afDb: AngularFirestore.

Second, Instead of this.callDoc = this.firestore.collection('calls').doc();, it should be this.callDoc = this.afDb.collection('calls').doc();

Comment: there is no AngularFirestore, i've tried it, so i confuse whether i use `afDb` or `firebase.firestore`

Comment: Did you AngularFirestoreModule in App module first (in angular)

Comment: You can follow this guide here https://github.com/angular/angularfire#readme